# Windows Authentication - prevent popup?

Tags: asp.net, windows, forms, authentication, iis

I'm trying to implement a web-view web part in sharepoint that will load up a small 'widget'y type thing I've got hosted on our local IIS. I desire to only show this web part to particular users, but cannot use the 'target audiences' feature of Sharepoint as we only use Foundation an the feature isn't present.

I'm currently attempting to use Windows authentication on the page, and it works fine for allowed users seamlessly infact - however, I was hoping there was a way if the user is denied, they don't get a popup asking for credentials, it would just redirect them to a blank page, thus the web part 'doesn't show' for them.

Is this possible using Windows authentication or do I need to use forms authentication against Active Directory and make them use a form to login? Can Forms Authentication be configured to seamlessly use AD groups and only show a login page when 'denied'?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying about a million different solutions that all basically led back to the problem of..
It's a pain to check if a user is authenticated before the 401 error is sent - as there is an initial 401 sent to the browser which then prompts for it for authentication..

I came up with a quick and dirty solution, as the project is small and not worth investing much more in.

I placed a very simple check in the page_load event like so, that checks for username if it isn't a postback (first load), and redirects if the static user list isn't found. Far far far from prfect, but it'll do.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var user = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToLower().ToString();
            if (user != "domain\\user")
            {
                Response.Redirect("/path/to/redirect/to.html");

            }
        }
```